# Entity Framework v4.1 LIKE

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

How do I have to build my query to result in an output SQL query like:

```
SELECT
[viewRegisters].[Id] AS [IdRegister]
WHERE Name LIKE '%a%bc'
```

OR

```
SELECT
[viewRegisters].[Id] AS [IdRegister]
WHERE Name LIKE 'a%b%c'
```

OR

```
SELECT
[viewRegisters].[Id] AS [IdRegister]
WHERE Name LIKE 'a%b%c%'
```

I'm using .Net Framework 4.0, Entity Framework v4.1 and C#.

EF v4.1 converts this type of linq queries from:

```
((IQueryable<T>)Data).Where(z => z.Field.Contains("a%b%c%"));
```

Into:

```
SELECT
[viewRegisters].[Id] AS [Id]
WHERE Name LIKE N'a~%b~%c~%' ESCAPE N'~'
```

That's not what I want. I want to be able to use the 'percent' symbol as I do directly in DB.

Comment: Usually .Contains results into a Like

Answer (score 7):

You must use [ESQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399359.aspx) if you want full wildcard support. Linq-to-entities is not able to do that and EFv4.1 code first (without EDMX) [doesn't have support for model defined functions](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/39b8d6cd-5c77-40e4-abf3-d620c79b8ff2) so the solution provided by @Johann Blais cannot be used.

I guess the code to run ESQL query can look like:

```
string command = "SELECT VALUE e FROM ContextName.DbSetName AS e WHERE e.Field LIKE 'a%b%c%'"
ObjectContext ctx = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
ObjectQuery<EntityType> query = new ObjectQuery<EntityType>(command, ctx);
ObjectResult<EtntiyType> result = query.Execute(MergeOption.AppendOnly);
```

Comment: Is there a way to use that in combination with PredicateBuilder<T> ?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using SQL Server, use the [`PATINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) function to do a pattern search.  You can access this function through EF using the [`SqlFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.aspx) class.

For example, the following EF query

```
context.ViewRegisters.Where(z => SqlFunctions.PatIndex("a%b%c%", z.Name) > 0);
```

will translate into

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM [dbo].[ViewRegisters] AS [Extent1]
WHERE (CAST(PATINDEX(N'a%b%c%', [Extent1].[Name]) AS int)) > 0
```

Comment: I'll try with this, the problem I see is that the pattern string needs to be sanitized (for sql injection).

Comment: I tried this on SQL server and in EF code and got a big fat fail every time.  It returned every single result in the table!

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = from viewRegister in context.ViewRegisters
where viewRegister.Name.Contains("yourname")
select viewRegister;
```