# Searchstrings with Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

**Hi,**

I need to let the enduser type search strings like :

**Volvo S70 OR S60** > All posts that contins Volvo OR S70 OR S60

**Volvo S70 NOT S60** > All posts that contains Volvo and S70 but not S60

**"Volvo S70"** > All posts that includes "Volvo S70" as one string

**Volvo S*** > All posts that contains Volvo and a word starting with S

**"Volvo S70" "Volvo S60" V*** > All posts that contains "Volvo S70" or "Volvo S60" Or a word starting on V

**Vo*l* S*** > * is treated as wildcards so in this case posts that contains Vo*l* or  S*

This is just a small part off possible combinations.

How do I handle this with Linq to Object?

I Know that I can use StartsWith, EndsWith, Contains but this will mean that I have to split the incoming search string, is this the only way? And how do I then handle strings like Vo*l*?

**BestRegards**

**Edit1:** The data have been fetched from database with entityframework, this means that the data is now in application (List)

Comment: So, `a b` means `a AND b` (Ex. 1), but `"a" "b"` means `"a" OR "b"` (Ex. 5)? Are you sure?

Comment: Is the data being searched stored in a data store and you want to query them out with the search string?  Or, is the data already available in your application and this is used to locate and narrow down options?

Comment: I think you have some logic problem there... how do you know s* is "start with" or "wildcard" check?

Comment: @Heinzi > Sorry, changed it now. My goal is that the search interpreted in a standardized why, Im not totaly sure that my examples shows this? But what I am after is somthing like google search (but it does not need to be that powerfull)

Comment: @Josh > I have already fetched the data objects with EntityFramework so the data is available in the application at this point.

Comment: If you did load data to the memory its not linq to entities but linq to objects

Comment: @musefan > My intentions is to provide a search that interpreted the search string in a global known way (maby like google with AND,OR,*,NOT and so on). s* should mean that we search for a word that starts on s and then anything else (*). If we instead use a search string like s*0 then we expect results like s60, s70 somthing0 and so on.

Comment: If your search has to be fast, the best way would be to use an existing product like [Lucene.Net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/). Look at the [QueryParser syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_1_0/queryparsersyntax.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to use [ESQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202036/entity-framework-v4-1-like/6202346#6202346) like this :

```
using (Entities context = new Entities())
      {
IQueryable<Ad> ads = context.CreateQuery<Ad>("SELECT VALUE C FROM Ads AS C WHERE C.Title LIKE @searchS OR C.Description LIKE @searchS", new ObjectParameter("searchS", searchS));

            ads = ads.Where(c => c.InactivatedDate.HasValue == inactive);
            ads = ads.Where(c => c.PublishedDate.HasValue && c.PublishedDate.Value.CompareTo(fetchAdsTo.Value) >= 1);

            output = ads.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to unleash the full power of text search you can use Lucene.NET .
It's not too easy to set up but it gives you a lot of power with full text searches and indexing. It can also be set up to work with LinqToEntities.

http://linqtolucene.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Since the data is already there and there's nothing in place in .NET to handle complex search strings with LINQ, I wonder if creating your own Query Extension Method would be too far in right field?

I'm thinking your best bet is to write your own parser which converts your search rules into regular expressions.  Your syntax may be too complicated for the simple LIKE functionality and indexed search is not an option unless you take the time to use Lucene, which I don't know much about.

This parser can then be called from a Query Extension Method to filter your data or find it.

Answer (score 0):

If `StartsWith, EndsWith, Contains` isn't good enough for you. You can use this function

`public ObjectQuery<T> Where(
    string predicate,
    params ObjectParameter[] parameters
)`

Like this (you can use any sql operator):

`ObjectQuery<Product> productQuery2 =
        productQuery1.Where("it.ProductID = @productID")`

Comment: I was hoping that there is somthing finished in .net(linq) to handle searchstrings. Say that I get a search string like this : volvo s*0, If I was to ask the database I could just replace the * with a % and then use like in the sql statment like this : Select from tabel where title like mySearchString > mySearchString = 'volvo s%0'. I will look in to your sugestion.