# How to write like statements in Entity Framework when the liked valued contains %

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-like

I know that `String.Contains('x')` would translate to `LIKE '%x%'`, and `String.StartsWith('x')` and `String.EndsWith('x')` would translate into `LIKE '%x'` and `LIKE 'x%'` respectively. However, I'm now in a situation in which I'm gonna build the LIKE operator regular expression clause in the business layer, and send it to the SQL Server through Entity Framework. I mean, now the end users builds the regular expression through a GUI and we need to retrieve the result based on that. For example, user creates something like `[Any Letter][Any Number]ab[Many Characters]` and we translate it into `[a-zA-Z][0-9]ab%`. Now we want to send this to SQL Server using Entity Framework. However, it seems that Entity Framework can't do this, and the query won't get the correct result back.

Any idea how we should implement this requirement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I escape a percentage sign in T-SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191449/how-do-i-escape-a-percentage-sign-in-t-sql) asking just yesterday

Comment: @gbn, that question wants to search for literal `%` sign. My question is to pass percentage sign directly from EF. It's not duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Entity framework is able to do this but linq-to-entities are not. You must use [Entity SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399560.aspx) and [LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399359.aspx) operator. [Some example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202036/entity-framework-v4-1-like/6202346#6202346).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Stored procedure and execute it using entity framework.

Comment: Seems the only **easy** way without getting into the trouble of learning a lot of new things. I think Microsoft should really implement the `Like` extension method for String type and translate that into SQL in EF. It would be really nice if developers can do something like `entities.Employees.Where(e => e.LastName.Like(pattern))`.