# Linq to Entities (EF 4.1): How to do a SQL LIKE with a wildcard in the middle ( '%term%term%')?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

I want to search for this:

```
Post Cereal
```

and get this:

```
Post Honey Nut Cereal
```

where the wild cards would be the spaces.

I know I could do a SPLIT and a series of ANDs and Contains() and translation to a Linq Expression for each term as a specification object, but isn't there a way to honor wildcards in the term sent to SQL?  I looked at SQL functions where it's in Linq to SQL, but I am not sure what it is in Linq to Entities.

I would like to do something like this:

```
term = '%' + term.Replace(' ', '%') + '%';
db.table.where( p => System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions
                     .SqlMethods.Like(p.fieldname, term) );
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I believe you could use [SqlFunctions.PatIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.patindex.aspx):

```
dt.Table.Where(p => SqlFunctions.PatIndex(term, p.fieldname) > 0);
```

SqlFunctions.PatIndex behaves the same as the [SQL LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) operator. It supports all standard wildcard characters including:

- **%**  Any string of zero or more characters.
- **_** (underscore)  Any single character.
- **[ ]** Any single character within the specified range ([a-f]) or set ([abcdef]).
- **[^]** Any single character not within the specified range ([^a-f]) or set ([^abcdef]).

SqlFunctions.PatIndex is often available when the SqlMethods.Like is not available (including within MVC controllers)

Comment: This deserves more up votes.  This worked perfectly for me without much complexity.

Comment: Dr. Zim is right, been looking for a solution for several hours and this is by far the simplest one I found.

Comment: I tried this in .NET and directly in TSQL and neither way worked out for me.  Using EF 5, .NET 4.5 and VS 2012

Comment: `SqlFunctions.PatIndex` is not supported in EF 4.0 - I get a not supported exception.

Answer (score 5):

It is probably easier to bypass LINQ and use an Entity SQL filter:

```
var query - db.table.Where("TRIM(fieldname) LIKE @pattern");
query.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("pattern", term)); // term == "%what%ever%"
```

and the type of `query` implements `IQueryable<TEntity>` so you can apply further LINQ operators.

Comment: I'm trying this out in LINQPad, but get this exception: `EntitySqlException: 'BusinessName' could not be resolved in the current scope or context. Make sure that all referenced variables are in scope, that required schemas are loaded, and that namespaces are referenced correctly.`  Where "BusinessName" is the column I am trying to filter on.  Can't figure out how to get past this.

Comment: @adrift You need to set up LINQPad with the context information, I barely use it so can't really help (IIRC I just referenced the assembly with the context and entity types).

Comment: Using Entity SQL is acutally the only way to do that - L2E doesn't support this type of wildcard searching. To fix you problem try to use `it.BusinessName`. Columns in ESQL must be prefixed and `it` is default prefix - [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202036/entity-framework-v4-1-like/6202346#6202346) is full example of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify  Ladislav's comment regarding `it.BusinessName`. I think what he is referring to is prefixing the field name with `.it`. The above solution works as long as you prefix the field name in the where clause with `it.`. Also I didn't need the TRIM() in my case.

```
var query - db.table.Where("it.fieldname LIKE @pattern");
query.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("pattern", term)); // term == "%what%ever%"
```

It worked perfectly against an Oracle database.