# Linq Like operator with constant length(can we use "_" ?)

Tags: c#, linq

my strings

```
    1st   110.01
    2nd   110.01.02
    3rd   110.02
    4th   110.02.01
    5th   110.03.02.03
    6th   110.04
```

Aim is get only last nodes. In the example I must take 2nd,4th, 5th and 6th.

So I have a recursive algorithm. But I need to know what the equal of

```
WHERE STR LIKE '110.__'
```

in LinQ.

I have searched to avoid duplicate question, but couldn't find. Thanks for any helps.

Comment: [SqlFunctions.PatIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.patindex.aspx)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689284/linq-to-entities-ef-4-1-how-to-do-a-sql-like-with-a-wildcard-in-the-middle

Comment: Is this LINQ to SQL, LINQ to EF, LINQ to objects or something else?

Comment: @user2864740 can you please write an answer for setting as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possiblity would be to check for `Length`.

```
 string str="110.";
.Where(i => i.StartsWith(str) && i.Lenghth == str.Length+2)
```

same with `WHERE column LIKE 110.__`

Comment: *"In the example I must take 2nd, 4th, 5th and 6th"* - this would only capture 1st, 3rd and 6th

Comment: this can work, but isn't there a character which is equal of "_" in sql. Single character.

Comment: @James `LIKE '110.__'` will never return 2,4,5. It will return only 1,3,6

Comment: @NaNNy. This would be a possibility, but then you cannot use EF - but It is not mentioned if EF is needed

Comment: I know, my point is your answer doesn't work as the OP expects it to.

Comment: @xxMUROxx This update of your answer is exactly solution of my question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-function [SqlFunctions.PatIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.patindex.aspx) (pattern index), as in

```
result = result.Where(p => SqlFunctions.PatIndex("110.__", p.Data) > 0)
               .Reverse()
               .Take(4);
```

**EDIT**

To clarify, what you asked for is to take the last *n* items, for instance 4. So to do that you can use use `.Reverse().Take(4)`, to reverse the order of the items, then take the first 4. If you want you xan then reverse the results back, so you would add another `.Reverse()` to the code above.

Comment: what is for reserve and take?