# Prevent EF from escaping wildcard character

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have something like this

```
var query = repo.GetQuery(); // IQueryable
query.Where(item => item.FieldName.Contains("xxx%yyy"));
```

It results in following statement on SQL server

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
// clipped
WHERE ([Extent1].[FieldName] LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE N''~'')',
    N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__0=N'%xxx~%yyy%'
```

`@p__linq__0=N'%xxx~%yyy%` causes the SQL server to look for `xxx%yyy` with `%` as literal (as it is escaped) while I would like it to match string like `xxx123yyy`, `xxxABCyyy`, `xxxANYTHINGyyy`, `xxxyyy` etc. Addition of `prefix %` and `suffix %` is fine but I could do it manually if needed.

In the above example I have simplified and written only one where condition but I have a dynamic logic that build the predicate with many of such keywords and I would like to allow the wildcards to be embedded inside the keywords. Is there a way to tell EF not to escape the % in the search keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. `Contains("xxx")` means that in SQL you want `LIKE '%xxx%'`. Linq-to-entities and none of its `String` mapped methods offer full wildcard searching = any wildcard character is always escaped. If you want to use wildcard searching you must use [Entity SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202036/entity-framework-v4-1-like/6202346#6202346).

Comment: Thanks. I found the linked question but was hoping there might have been something new. I am using ExecuteStoreQuery with hand crafted SQL along with parameters. Earlier I was using PredicateBuilder with static binding and not everything is strings :(

Comment: @amit_g: If you are working with SQL Server, then there is a workaround (`SqlFunctions.PatIndex`) which allows you to use LINQ queries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202036/entity-framework-v4-1-like/8000303#8000303 . I have no idea though about the performance of that function in SQL Server compared to an ordinary `LIKE` (but it's probably not better).